# save the sql output in text file

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, file, jdbc

[image: SQL required output]

i need some buildit method of any class that can give output me like described in below figure 
(in xyz.txt) file . i tried by using my own user define method when i pass the ResultSet object to it. It will going to save all record in txt file using FileWriter but some time order changed or even columns not fit in area etc. so i need java buildit method like `SQL Command line Client` which give output like below then definately there is java method available for save the output in txt file

in need like this method public void convert(ResultSet rs,String fileoutputname){}
and if rs="select * from employees" output save in fileoutput.txt

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the exact output of the *mysql* command line tool, I would recommend  simply executing that command and capturing its output.

Presumably you know the *SQL* that you want to run, so that can be interpolated into the command you execute (via the `--execute` option). You can then save the output to a file or perform any other transformation on said output.

Here is a link with some options/examples for running system commands in *Java*:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Comment: i need any method that take argument ResultSet and outputTextfileName and give us output as shown above :(

Comment: You said you needed the output to be **exactly** (in terms of formatting and sequence and everything) like the command line tool, which is why I recommended it. What is the code that you tried so far?

Comment: but this is for cmd can i use this one on MySql 5.5 CommandLine client

Comment: Yes, the *mysql* command line tool (assuming it is installed) is what you would execute using one of the methods I linked. Instead of passing the `ResultSet` in, you would pass the *SQL* you want to execute, and get back the results.